# How to relate two entities in Jhipster JDL?

Tags: jhipster

Let's say you have a Jhipster app that has a Profile and needs to register which Profiles follows other profiles with 2 attributes: one for the user that is following (user Profile) and another for the followed user (followed Profile). Something like:

```
entity Profile {
    creationDate Instant required
}

entity Follows {
  creationDate Instant
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Profile{follows(user)} to Follows{profile(id)}
    Profile{follows(followed)} to Follows{profile(id)}
}
```

The problem with this is that the Follows.java has 2 identical atributes even when the names are different follows(user) & follows(followed):

```
@ManyToOne
private Profile profile;
```

... instead of...

```
@ManyToOne
private Profile user;

@ManyToOne
private Profile followed;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same relationship name for both relationships, but each relationship name needs to be different or else the fields conflict.

```
relationship (OneToMany | ManyToOne | OneToOne | ManyToMany) {
  <from entity>[{<relationship name>[(<display field>)]}] to <to entity>[{<relationship name>[(<display field>)]}]
}
```

[JDL Relationship Declaration Docs](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#relationshipdeclaration)

In the case of your JDL sample, I changed the display field from `user`/`followed` to `id` as those fields do not exist on the entity.  The important change is that the relationship names are unique.

```
relationship OneToMany {
    Profile{followed(id)} to Follows{followed(id)}
    Profile{following(id)} to Follows{following(id)}
}
```

Comment: Can you use the example to give the solution, because Profile{follows(user)} to Follows{profile(id)} & Profile{follows(followed)} to Follows{profile(id)} OR Follows{user} to Profile & Follows{followed} to Profile does not work. Thanks

Comment: You are still using the same relationship names.  Those need to be unique.  If you don't declare a relationship name, it defaults to the entity name.  I added an example using your JDL

Answer (score 0):

```
entity Profile {
    creationDate Instant required
}

entity Follows {
  creationDate Instant
}

relationship ManyToOne{
    Follows{user} to Profile
    Follows{followed} to Profile
}
```

Comment: Please consider explaining what your answer does, and why it works.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. I still get two identical @ManyToOne
    private Profile profile; which make to an error. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

[Supposing you want relation between Rooms and Patient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrvTW.png)

You can have these entities

```
entity NmsPatient {
photo ImageBlob
}

entity NmsRoom {
code String required,
name String required
}

entity NmsPatientRoom {
    begin ZonedDateTime,
    end ZonedDateTime
}
```

And then

```
relationship ManyToOne {
 NmsPatientRoom{patient} to NmsPatient,
 NmsPatientRoom{room} to NmsRoom
}
```